# uib-tooltip as text in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have some problems with appending uib-tooltip to the view.

**Controller:** ('v' is an array)

```
$scope.video_link = function (v) {
    var del = "";
    if(v.deleted == 1) {
        del = '<i class="fa fa-times" uib-tooltip="Video deleted"></i>';
    }
    var link = del+'<a href="'+v.video_id+'">' + v.video_name + '</a>';
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(link);
}
```

**View:**

```
<span ng-bind-html="video_link(v)"></span>
```

Everything works well but tooltip itself don't show up.

I know I can move "uib-tooltip" to the view (and it works fine) but I need to build the whole link in Controller. Is it possible to made it work properly?

Answer (score 0):

To make dynamically created by code `md-elements` to work you need to call

`componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();`

which initializes all new bootstrap components added to the view `i.e. those are added programatically`

`componentHandler.upgradeElement(elem)`

if you want to initilize only 1 element

**ALSO** make sure you call one of these functions after the element is added to the view and not before.

`componentHandler` global object is created when you import `uibootstrap` library to your project.

[componentHandler reference](https://getmdl.io/started/)